# Why do crosslinked defstructs cause stack overflows?

Tags: data-structures, common-lisp, sbcl, clozure-cl

While playing around with graphs, I got a curious error I didn't quite understand. The code below reproduces the problem.

```
;; Define struct to store a node with links to other nodes.
(defstruct node properties links)

;; Make two nodes
(setf a (make-node :properties '(:name a))
      b (make-node :properties '(:name b)))

;; Create link from b to a. This works fine...
(push b (node-links a))

;; ... but this crosslink makes lisp chase its own tail for a while and then crash with a stack overflow.
(push a (node-links b))
```

I got the same result with SBCL and Clozure. Setting `*print-length*` to a manageable value did not work.

So my questions is: Why doesn't this code create the same kind of infinite printing loop as a circular list (i.e., no stack overflow and stoppable with Ctrl-C). Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,
 Paulo

Comment: When I run your code in SBCL or CLISP (with or without SLIME), I can still Ctrl+C out of the loop. I don't know why it isn't interruptible on your end.

Comment: I guess Ctrl+C failed on my end for the prosaic reason that I am using a crappy machine with lots of open programs, so the heap blows up before the machine "digests" the keystrokes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*print-length*` controls the number of elements in a list. You're looking for `*print-level*`. This works fine for me.

```
(let ((*print-level* 3))
  (format t "~W~%" a))
;; Output: #S(NODE :PROPERTIES (:NAME A)
;;  :LINKS (#S(NODE :PROPERTIES # :LINKS #)))
```

Alternatively, you could use `*print-circle*` to detect cycles and print them in an even nicer way.

```
(let ((*print-circle* t))
  (format t "~W~%" a))
;; Output: #1=#S(NODE :PROPERTIES (:NAME A)
;;  :LINKS (#S(NODE :PROPERTIES (:NAME B) :LINKS (#1#))))
```

Here, it actually detects the cycle and prints `#1#`, a reference to the `#1=` to show that it's the same object.